# How to manage compilation of C++ header-only libraries across shared objects

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, eigen

I'm developing a large software package consisting of many packages which are compiled to shared objects. For performance reasons, I want to compile Eigen 3 (a header-only library) with vector instructions, but the templated methods are being compiled all over the place. How can I ensure that the Eigen functions are compiled into a specific object file?

This software consists of ~2000 individual packages. To keep development going at a reasonable pace, the recommended way of compiling the program is to sparsely check out some of the packages and compile them, after which the program can be executed using precompiled (by some CI system) shared libraries.

The problem is that part of my responsibility is to optimise the CPU time of the program. In order to do so, I wanted to compile the package I am working on (let's call it `A.so`) with the `-march` flag so Eigen can exploit modern SIMD processor extensions.

Unfortunately, because Eigen is a header-only library, the Eigen functions are compiled into many different shared objects. For example, one of the most CPU intensive methods called in `A.so` is the matrix multiplaction kernel which is compiled in `B.so`. Many other Eigen functions are compiled into `C.so`, `D.so`, etc. Since these objects are compiled for older, more widely implemented instruction set extensions, they are not compiled with AVX, AVX2, etc.

Of course, one possible solution is to include packages `B`, `C`, `D`, etc. into my own sparse compilation but this negates the advantage of compiling only a part of the project. In addition, it leaves me including ever more and more packages if I really want to vectorise all linear algebra operations in the code of package `A`.

What I am looking for is a way to compile all the Eigen functions that package `A` uses into `A.so`, as if the Eigen functions were defined with the static keyword. Is this possible? Is there some mechanism in the compiler/linker that I can leverage to make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

One obvious solution is to hide these symbols. This happens (if I understand the problem properly) because these functions are exported and can be used by other subsequently loaded libraries.

When you build your library and link against the other libraries, the linker reuses what it can. And the old packages as well. I hope you don't require these libraries for your own build?

So two options:

- Force the loading of `A` before the other libraries (but if you need the other libraries, I don't think this is doable),
- Tell the linker that these functions should not be visible by other libraries (`visibility=hidden` by default).

I saw something similar happening with a badly compiled 3rd-party library. It was built in debug mode, shipped in the product, and all of a sudden one of our libraries experienced a slow down. The map files identified where the culprit debug function came from, as it exported all its symbols by default.

Comment: If on Linux, also consider using the `visibility` [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html); see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)

Comment: @Basile indeed, that's what I thought by `visibility`, thanks for the link.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using symbol hiding. If I understand correctly, I would have to configure the hiding of Eigen symbols on _all_ objects, correct? Is there a way to prevent the linker reusing the Eigen symbols in other objects without changing the source code for those objects?

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe someone will answer with the silver bullet!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to change visibility without modifying the code is to filter symbols during linking stage using version scripts -> https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html. You'll need something like

`{
    global: *;
    local:
        extern "C++"
        {
            Eigen::*;
            *Eigen::internal::*;
        };
};`